# Помогите корректно отобразить значение из моего класса

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

Написал запрос при котором я получаю класс семестр , отображаю его значения в виде имени и получаю его id.Соответственно когда я выбираю нужный мне семестр в выпадающем списке мне предоставляется тот семестр , который я выбирал. Но мне также необходимо отобразить в другом поле его длительность , я могу это сделать если создаю цикл ForEach и с помощью него извлекает это значение , но он выводит абсолютно все имеющиеся значения , а не то которое мне нужно. Подскажите как правильно мне это сделать ? Для отображения я использую jsp страницу , jstl и формы spring. Сейчас страница выглядит так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также прикладываю содержимое jsp :

```html
<form:form action="allSemestrsSem" method="get" id="selectSemestr" modelAttribute="semestr">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 50px">

      <select name="selectSemestr">

        <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
          <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 20px">
      <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="select" /></td>
    </security:authorize>
  </tr>

  <tr height="80px" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">
    <td colspan="3">Semester duration:
      <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr"> ${semestr.duration} </c:forEach>
    </td>
  </tr>

</form:form>
```

И на всякий случай мой контроллер :

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/allSemestrsSem", method = RequestMethod.GET) public String allSemestrs(@RequestParam(name = "selectSemestr") String selectSemestr, Model model) { List
<Semestr> semestr = service.getSemestr(); model.addAttribute("semestr", semestr); List
  <Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getDisciplineSemestrId(Integer.valueOf(selectSemestr)); model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines); return "semestr"; }
```

Comment: Есть мнение, что тут не нужно в цикле снова перебирать ВСЕ значения, а выбрать только тот семестр, id которого сейчас выбран в `select name="selectSemestr"`

Comment: Да , но вот в том то и вопрос как это сделать? Это понимание было у меня еще и до написания этого вопроса , у меня нет знаний как это реализовать с помощью HTML

Comment: Не в HTML суть. Я не имел дело с JSP и JSTL, но на чистом javascript можно было бы получить значение выбранного option примерно так: `document.getElementById('selectSemestr').options[n].value` где n - номер выбранного option, который можно получить так: `document.getElementById('selectSemestr').options.selectedIndex`.  Но мой пример сработает, если у селекта будет не только имя, но и id.

Comment: К сожалению в моем проекте не используется JavaScript